# How to install additional package in anaconda3?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, anaconda, conda

I get this error while installing. And when I use `sudo`, it says `command not found`.

```
$ conda update conda
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

environment location: /home/raworm/anaconda

added / updated specs: 
- conda


The following packages will be UPDATED:

conda: 4.4.10-py36_0 --> 4.4.11-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(481): An error occurred while 
uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.4.10-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

This is what happens when I use `sudo`:

```
 $ sudo conda update conda
 sudo: conda: command not found
```

Neither can I use `pip` in `sudo`, I keep getting the same error:

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you find solution for this by any chance? I am facing same issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `which conda pip`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All conda commands must be run without super user privileges. That's why `sudo conda` command doesn't work.

You may have run conda installation bush file with super user privileges while installing. The user (`raworm`) running conda doesn't have write permissions to paths(`/home/raworm/anaconda`) it needs to modify in the environment, then conda can't do anything. To solve this problem you need to change permissions to paths (`/home/raworm/anaconda`).

To change permissions to paths (`/home/user/anaconda`) using:

```
sudo chown -R user /home/user/anaconda
```

Comment: This does not specify how to change the permission to that specific directory.